# Twiml-Autopress digit and Input it in a gather function

Tags: flask, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, ivr

I need to make twilio to pause for the given time and need to automatically press the values and after pressing the digits, these digits should be passed as gather input. Is that possible ?
My code :

gather = Gather(num_digits=10, action='/process-ivr-input',timeout="5")

```
    gather.say(f"Please wait for {keys[pos]} seconds")
    gather.pause(length= keys[pos])
    gather.say("Getting the code ")
    response.append(gather)
    response.say('We didn\'t receive any input. So connecting to the agent')
    flag = 1
    response.redirect('/intiate-call')
```